# Django Model Interaction and Showing Changes

Tags: python, django

I've been having this weird problem with Django. In the website when I create a model and it redirects to page where I list models, the new model is not listen yet. Then, when I refresh the page, the model is there. How can I make sure that database call is finished before redirecting? It feels not synchronized and buggy. It happens, when deleting the model too. Thanks for help.

P.S My application is hosted on Google App Engine and I am using Django-non-rel.

Here is some code of creating an object:

```
def new_object(request, template_name, parent=None):
  form = ObjectForm(request.POST or None, user=request.user)
  if form.is_valid():
    model = form.save()
    model.owner = request.user
    model.parent = parent
    model.save()     
    if parent:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(parent.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

  data = { 'form' : form, 'parent': parent } 
  context = RequestContext(request)    
  return render_to_response(template_name, data, context)
```

Save function of the object

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
   ''' On save, update timestamps '''
   if not self.id:
        self.created_date = datetime.datetime.today()
   self.modified_date = datetime.datetime.today()

   if self.parent:
       self.parent.modified_date = self.modified_date
       self.parent.save()
```

Comment: without the smallest piece of code (like your view(s) and model(s)) noone will be able to tell...

Comment: Help us out, and we'll help you out :)  Post some code.

Comment: Thanks for elegantly pointing that out to me. It's my first post on stackoverflow :)